# Convert tensorflow model from python - input_shape

Tags: keras, tensorflow.js

I am trying to use a Keras model trained on Google Colab in tensorflow.js but I am getting this "Error: The first layer in a Sequential model must get an `inputShape` or `batchInputShape` argument." There are already topics about it, but none of the solutions actually work.
I am using a slightly modified pix 2 pix architecture - based on a tutorial posted on tensorflow pages.

This is the generator model I am trying to convert:

```
def build_gen_model():

  inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=(None,img_size,img_size,channels))


  input_shape=(img_size,img_size,channels)

  n = int(math.log2(img_size))

  downstack = [
               downsample(64,5,batch_norm=False,input_shape=input_shape ),
               downsample(128,5),
               downsample(256,5)
  ]

  for _ in range(n-3):
    downstack.append(downsample(512,5))

  upstack = []

  for _ in range(n-4):
    upstack.append(upsample(512,5,dropout=True))

  upstack.append(upsample(256,5))
  upstack.append(upsample(128,5))
  upstack.append(upsample(64,5))

  last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(channels,kernel_size=5,strides=2,padding='same',activation='tanh')

  x=inputs

  skips =[]
  for d in downstack:
    x = d(x)
    skips.append(x)

  skips = reversed(skips[:-1])

  for u, skip in zip(upstack,skips):
    x = u(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x,skip])

  x = last(x)

  return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
```

I have added (which I think might not be necessary) an extra parameter that allows me to add extra input shape to the first downsample layer, but it also does not help.

```
def downsample(filters, kernel_size, batch_norm=True, input_shape=None):
  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  if not input_shape:
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters,kernel_size=kernel_size,strides=2,padding='same'))
  else:
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters,kernel_size=kernel_size,strides=2,padding='same',input_shape=input_shape))

  if batch_norm:
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
  return model
```

I am saving to .h5 and then converting using tensorflowjs installed with pip locally on my PC. The resulting JSON actually does have 'batch_input_shape' appearing. So I am puzzled...

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the converter ? You can manually add the `batch_input_shape` in the model.json

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I am using the latest version from pip - 1.7.4.
Thing is that 'batch_input_shape' does exist in the JSON file. So..maybe the .js library is not up-to-date. I don't remember the version now, but I will check if it is the latest.

Comment: You can add it yourself manually in the config of the layer if missing

Comment: well this is the beginning of my model:



{"format": "layers-model", "generatedBy": "keras v2.3.0-tf", "convertedBy": "TensorFlow.js Converter v1.7.4r1", "modelTopology": {"keras_version": "2.3.0-tf", "backend": "tensorflow", "model_config": {"class_name": "Model", "config": {"name": "model_4", "layers": [{"class_name": "InputLayer", "config": {"batch_input_shape": [null, 256, 256, 1], "dtype": "float32", "sparse": false, "ragged": false, "name": "input_3"},